# Plotly not plotting bars in barchart

Tags: python, plotly

I am doing sentiment analysis on tweets and have attempted to plot date vs sentiment in a bar chart. I have used to following code to do so:

```py
fig = px.bar(df, y='score', x='date')
fig.show()
```

the result of this is:

[image: Bar chart - no data?]

this results in a bar chart that doesn't have any bars.

I have checked my dataframe and the data is indeed correct.

```
         score                 date
0     0.350000  2020-10-12 22:22:39
1     0.088312  2020-10-16 11:20:20
2     0.450000  2020-10-16 11:14:42
3     0.800000  2020-11-16 14:19:29
4     0.000000  2021-01-06 14:16:30
...        ...                  ...
1862 -0.225000  2019-01-04 01:19:17
1863  0.215000  2019-01-03 14:52:13
1864  0.127320  2019-01-02 13:35:30
1865  0.202841  2019-01-01 00:40:26
1866  1.000000  2020-01-01 00:17:52
```

I have further tried to adjust how plotly recongises the data, but none of the catagories stated on their website have fixed my issue.

```py
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(type='-'))
```

I don't understand why my data works with matplotlib and altair, but not with ploty.

EDIT:

Added examples of DF entries

| score | date |
| --- | --- |
| 0.35 | 2020-10-12 22:22:39 |
| 0.0883116883116883 | 2020-10-16 11:20:20 |
| 0.45 | 2020-10-16 11:14:42 |
| 0.7999999999999999 | 2020-11-16 14:19:29 |
| 0.0 | 2021-01-06 14:16:30 |
| 0.175 | 2020-10-24 02:06:09 |
| 0.1744805194805194 | 2020-10-25 12:08:59 |
| -0.375 | 2020-11-16 16:11:09 |
| 0.0 | 2020-10-25 19:18:16 |
| 0.35 | 2020-11-21 21:20:39 |
| 0.3666666666666666 | 2020-10-16 04:23:33 |
| 0.1041666666666667 | 2020-10-19 18:08:38 |
| -0.0583333333333333 | 2020-10-21 12:06:28 |
| 0.1516666666666666 | 2020-10-26 11:36:35 |
| 0.0 | 2020-10-27 00:11:29 |

Comment: I don't see any x-axis date in the data. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, I only printed the score, i will adjust to also add the date.

Comment: Ran the updated data and code. The bar graph is displayed, but the granularity of the time series is too fine to be visible. You can see this if you zoom in on the graph. (Selecting a rectangle on the graph will zoom in on that area.

Comment: Yes, I tried this too, however, I do not even see single bars when zooming in. This makes me suspect that something is off?

Comment: What is the version of plotly that you are using?

Comment: @AS11 my version is 4.14.3

Comment: Could you provide the code for your data frame so that it is easily reproducible

Comment: @AS11 The database was build using the spaCy sentiment analyser, I have provided a link to a csv of the dataframe: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CLpXwAI6cylfE0uKoPSIpouhZoNQ146XwBA-vOLu338/edit?usp=sharing) I also added 10 entries of the DF in my question.